# Convert NSDictionary to std::vector

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I want to convert an NSDictionary mapping integers to floating point values into a C++ std::vector where the key from the original NSDictionary is the index into the vector.

I have code that I thought would work, but it seems to create a vector larger than the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary. I'm guessing its something to do with the way I am indexing into the vector.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have:

```
 static std::vector<float> convert(NSDictionary* dictionary)
  {
      std::vector<float> result(16);
      NSArray* keys = [dictionary allKeys];
      for(id key in keys)
      {        
          id value = [dictionary objectForKey: key];
          float fValue = [value floatValue];
          int index = [key intValue];
          result.insert(result.begin() + index, fValue);
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::map`. It's NSDictionary's counterpart in STL. Maybe your keys are not ordered and you can't insert index arbitrarily on `std::vector`. You need to do it in order: 0, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Because I am writing a plugin that gives me an NSDictionary, and want to pass that along to an API I am using which requires a std::vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialising a vector with a number creates that many entries to begin with. In this case, your vector will start with 16 elements, and each insert will add elements, so you'll end up with 16 + *N* elements.

If you want to change an element to a new value simply assign to it. Don't use insert:

```
result[index] = fValue;
```

However, you really should just use `map<int, float>`:

```
std::map<int, float> result;
NSArray* keys = [dictionary allKeys];
for(id key in keys)
{        
    id value = [dictionary objectForKey: key];
    float fValue = [value floatValue];
    int index = [key intValue];
    result[index] = fValue;
}
```

Comment: The first solution looks like it might be the right one. I can't use std::map because I am writing a plugin that gives me an NSDictionary, and want to pass that along to an API I am using which requires a std::vector.

By the by, how do you get code blocks to work?

Comment: @ekj: One question per question, please.

Comment: sorry, I just meant in my stack overflow post. But I figured that out :-D. I'm a n00b here

Answer (score 0):

Since you say your keys should become the indexes into the vector, you can sort your keys.
Untested example:

```
static std::vector<float> convert(NSDictionary* dictionary)
{
    std::vector<float> result;
    NSArray* keys = [dictionary allKeys];
    result.reserve([keys count]); // since you know the extent
    for (id key in [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)])
    {        
        id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
        float fValue = [value floatValue];
        int index = [key intValue];
        result.push_back(fValue);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think the sorting is unnecessary if the assumption is made that the keys form a contiguous set (if sorted). The way I now have it working is to initialise the vector to [keys count], then just use result[index] = fValue

Comment: That will probably be a more efficient implementation.  But I don't think there's any need for a map, was my point.