# NSMutableArray to std::vector

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, stdvector, objective-c++

Is it possible to convert the contents of an NSMutableArray to a std::vector? And if so, should this be done in the Objective-C or C++ code?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You'd use a bridging cast on each item in the mutable array to a void pointer and store that in the `std::vector`. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298912/convert-nsdictionary-to-stdvector?rq=1 It'd have to be done in Objective-C++ .mm file of course.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comments have been able to get me started.

Comment: @Brandon, sorry but you can use templates of Objective-C++ to create, specification to any Objective-C type. For example: std::set<NSObject*>, std::vector<__weak NSObject*>. Second container will store weak references.

Comment: Also don't forget that cast to void* is not safe to ARC. But it is a other story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a vector with any Objective-C type.
For example to store a NSString instance into a vector, you can use next code:

```
    NSMutableArray<NSString*>* array = [@[@"1", @"2"] mutableCopy];

    __block std::vector<NSString*> vectorList;
    vectorList.reserve([array count]);
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        vectorList.push_back(obj);
    }];

    for (std::vector<NSString*>::const_iterator iterator = vectorList.cbegin(); iterator != vectorList.cend(); iterator++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", *iterator);
    }
```

You should use it in Objective-C++ files, because C++ does not have syntax for Objective-C (files with mm extension).

If you need to convert a data inside NSMutableArray to different representation, for example, NSNumber to int or NSString to std::string, you should create it by hand.

Comment: nit: I think there is a small optimization where you can initialize the vector and then reserve the amount of memory needed to copy the array (`vectorList.reserve([array count])`). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108854/initializing-the-size-of-a-c-vector/25108894