# When I pass a string from .mm file to .cpp file , the program compiles fine but at the run time I get an error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in Xcode

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos

My .mm file -

```
std::string argv([argumentString UTF8String]);
int x = obj.zmain(argumentCount,argv);
```

obj is object of type ZMain.

My .cpp file -

```
    int ZMain::zmain(int argc,std::string argv) {

        std::istringstream iss(argv);
        std::string s;
        char *paramArray[argc];
        int i=0;
        while ( getline( iss, s, ' ' ) ) {
            strcpy(paramArray[i],s.c_str());
            std::cout<<paramArray[i]<<std::endl;
            i++;
        }
       return 0;
}
```

I get error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" sometimes inside the loop, sometimes before the loop and sometimes after the loop. What would be the problem?

Comment: `paramArray[i]` are all uninitialized pointers, undefined behavior. Use a vector of strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSArray<NSString *> *argv = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]` on the Objective-C side, which contains the parsed values already (see this question - [Accessing command line arguments in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146849/accessing-command-line-arguments-in-objective-c)).

Then convert it to `std::vector<string>` before passing to zmain.cpp (see [NSMutableArray to std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615381/nsmutablearray-to-stdvector) ).